# Recommendation for testing a long, complex method

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I've got a fairly long and intricate C# method - just shy of 200 lines - that I'm trying to figure out how to test effectively. I've already got about 50 unit tests for this particular method, but I'm not satisfied with them, for two reasons: (1) Experience has shown that they've missed some problematic scenarios, and (2) the tests are complicated enough that I'm having trouble confirming that they're actually testing what I want them to test.

The strategy that I'm adopting to ameliorate this problem is to refactor the method into half a dozen smaller methods, which should individually be easier to test. So far, so good - nothing unusual about this.

But I'm worried about the fact that these new methods - which I should normally make private, as I can't foresee them being used by any other production classes - either (a) need to be public, so that they can be tested, or (b) if I leave them private, I need to jump through weird reflection-style hoops to test them. Since the class in question  isn't intended for external consumption, I'm not *horribly* worried about exposing these ostensibly private methods as public, but it still strikes me as having a weird code smell that I'd prefer to avoid.

What have other folks done in similar scenarios? What sort of strategies should I be adopting to help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spliiting the method up is a good start.

You don't need to make them `public`. Make the methods `internal` and use the [InternalsVisibleTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-Attribute to grant your unit test assembly access to them.

If you have a Visual Studio version that supports it, use the "Analyze code coverage" feature to check if you have tested every line.

Comment: Great suggestion about `internal` and the `[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo()]` attribute. Don't know why I didn't think of that.